# Apache Netbeans Output Window overwrite messages

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

Is it possible to setting the output window, do not overwrite the messages? I tried to set the same font type and size in Tools-Options-Miscellaneous Output and Terminal, but it didnt help.

Attempt 2: Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Terminal > History Size -
Set from 5000 to 50000 but it didn't help.

Same problem in running program. Scanner.nextline() typing overwrite the end of the println() printed text.

Here is an example of the problem:

[image: Output Window Picture]

Output Window Settings

[image: Output Window Settings]

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.5
Java: 16.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 16.0.1+9-24
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 16.0.1+9-24
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF8

---

File -> New Project -> Java with Ant -> Java Application
Run -> Run Project (Sample) F6 
Sample code and Output Window
[image: Sample code and Output Window]

---

Not a real solutoin but (maybe) its a good workaround:
Tools -> Options -> Output -> Font: set to "Tahoma 11"

[image: Workaround]

Comment: Try increasing the value of **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Terminal > History Size** from the default value of 5,000. If that resolves your issue then please post an answer to your own question, and also accept it since accepted answers are helpful to the community. But if that change doesn't help, update your question accordingly.

Comment: Based on the screen shot it's not quite accurate to state that messages are being overwritten. Instead, within the stack trace there is an issue on lines containing a method name in red font: the associated embedded link to the source code in blue font is not formatted correctly. I can't reproduce the problem. Please update the question to show a screen shot of the **Output** window settings (**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Output**). Also, if you click one of those blue links, does it still work and display the relevant source code in the edit window?

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem. Please [provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue. Give enough information so that others can follow your instructions to create, build and run a project to reproduce the problem in NetBeans. I suspect the issue may lie with the way the output is being written to the Output window/console, so the application can probably be just a few lines long. Also be sure to detail how to create and run the project (Maven? Ant? Gradle? Project type? Run with(out) debug? etc...).

Comment: I replicated your example but I still can't reproduce your problem, though I am using NB 12.6/JDK 17, and you are using NB 12.5/JDK 16. However, note that NetBeans 12.5 doesn't formally support JDK 16 (see [the Deployment Platforms section](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html)), but I doubt if that is relevant. All I can suggest as a possible workaround is upgrading to NB 12.6/JDK 17, or NB 13/JDK 17 to see if the problem persists. You don't need to uninstall NB 12.5 to do that; two instances of NetBeans can safely coexist. And please post an answer if you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I must use JDK 16, so I live with this annoying but not a real problem.